# Beginner doubts on List Comprehension Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am currently doing the *99 Haskell problems* that are on the Wiki. Having said that, I was doing the problem number *26* that requires a program that can write all the combinations with *n* elements in a given set. I did my implementation with plenty of functions and the program seems correct. But my questions arise not from this, but from one of the solutions of the Haskell Wiki

```
combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations 0 _  = [ [] ]
combinations n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs
                           , ys <- combinations (n-1) xs']
```

I understood that `y:xs` is resolved for every list that is given by function **`tails`**, resulting in lists of possible values, but I can't understand how the `ys` value are made so that `y:ys` give me all the correct solutions.

And another more important question that I have is why these two expressions have diferent results?

```
[xs | y:xs <- tails [1,2,3]]
[[2,3],[3],[]]

[xs | y:xs <- tails [1,2,3], z <- xs]
[[2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

They may not have any practical use, but they demonstrated for me a Haskell beginner, a very strange behaviour. Why applying `z <- xs` change the value of `xs`?

Comment: If you expect the last two expressions to have the same value, then it is due to a misunderstanding of what list comprehensions actually mean. You don't say what your understanding is (or even what you expect the output the expressions to be) so it's hard to see how it can be corrected (NB: the last expression is equivalent to `concatMap (\ys -> case ys of { y:xs -> concatMap (\z -> [xs]) xs; [] -> [] }) (tails [1,2,3])`)

Comment: I thought that list comprehension in Haskell meant the set of values given by the expression before the guard which respect the constraints given in the right side of the guard. Is my idea wrong? Because according to this thought applying z <- xs shouldn't change the value of xs in any way...

Comment: Your vague intuition may be accurate in some cases, but as you've seen it doesn't actually correspond the semantics of list comprehensions. See [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) for the semantics of list comprehensions. You can use the semantics to translate your expressions to ones defined with regular functions, and then convince yourself that the two expressions are not equal.

Comment: The value of `xs` doesn't change, but list comprehensions give you a *list* of values, not a set. In particular, repeated values are possible if you have nested generators on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have different results due to the [comprehension desugaring rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11). If we have

```
[ expression | a <- as, b <- bs ]
```

then we will get

```
concatMap (\a -> concatMap (\b -> [expression]) bs) as
```

Even if `b` isn't used in `expression`, we will still end up with more elements. For example `concatMap (const [1]) [1..10]` will lead to `replicate 10 1`. So if you add another list in your comprehension you change the number of `concatMap` and therefore also the number of outputs (unless the list contained exactly one element):

```
[a | a <- [1..10]]             -- results in [1..10]
[a | a <- [1..10], _ <- [1,2]] -- results in [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...,9,9,10,10]
[a | _ <- [1,2], a <- [1..10]] -- results in [1..10] ++ [1..10]
```

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
combinations n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs
                           , ys <- combinations (n-1) xs']
```

reads as: to choose `n` elements from `xs`, choose any `y` in `xs`, and name the tail of elements coming after `y` as `xs'`. Then recursively choose `n-1` elements from `xs'`, naming any such choice `ys`. The result is formed by all the `y:ys` that can be generated in this way.

Convince yourself that this algorithm indeed takes all the possible choices (precisely: all the choices which respect the ordering given by the original list `xs`).

Note a few corner cases, which are handled correctly.
First, inside `tails xs` we also find the empty tail `[]`, but this is ignored since it is not of the form `y:xs'`. 
Then, the tail `xs'` could be shorter than `n-1` elements. In such case `ys <- combinations (n-1) xs'` will find zero choices for `ys`, so no "output" will be generated for this `xs'`.

Finally, about you last question. Consider this example:

```
[ 42 | x <- [1,2,3 ] ] == [ 42, 42, 42 ]
```

The value of `x` does not affect the value of `42`, since `42` is constant, but it does affect its multiplicity. This is very similar to the imperative loop `for x in [1,2,3]: print(42)`, which produces its output several times.